# How to response a touch event which begin to touch down outside of a view and drag enter it in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I want to response this kind of touch event on a view:begin to touch down outside of the view and drag enter it. I have tried to use the iOS UIControlEvent such as UIControlEventTouchDragEnter,UIControlEventTouchDragInside and the UIGesture, and I found no way can do this directly.
Finally, I implement it with my own way:Create a custom subclass of UIView and overwrite the method (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event and forward touch event up to the responder chain. In the touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded method of parent view, I use the location of UITouch object to judge touch down outside of the view and drag enter it.
I am not satisfied with this way. Is there anyone can tell me a more efficient and elegant way to work out it? Thank you very much for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2):

> begin to touch down outside of the view and drag enter it

You can never do this more "elegantly" because if your initial touch down is outside the view, then it is not associated with this view and never will be. Whatever view the touch's initial hit test associates it with, that is the view that will *always* be this touch's view throughout the gesture, and touch events will be sent only to that view. The default definition of hit testing is that the view that the initial touch is *inside* is the hit-test view, and that, by hypothesis, is *not* your view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.