# How Do I Trigger a Button By Sliding Onto It?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, interface-builder

I'm working on an app with a musical keyboard component.

I need 2 types of "sent events" to trigger the keys of the keyboard (UIButtons).

1) "Touch Down" triggers the buttons they way I need it to

2) The 2nd way I need buttons to be triggered is by sliding onto a button,from another button/key to the side of it as if it is "touched down" upon, when it is slid upon from the left or right.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: @matt Ok.  That is a good explanation.  Unfortunately it means I will have start over from scratch and create some type of "superview" that can manage the button actions I need... Thanks for letting me know that what I was trying to achieve is not possible with basic UIButtons and "sent events" in IB.

Comment: @matt  Do you know of any tutorial on how to implement something like this in Swift?

Comment: @matt I only know this makes sense at a broad level.  I have no idea how to implement this.  I spent months on my current keyboard setup for my app (it's an isometric keyboard with square keys in an 8x8 grid within a scrolling view).  The idea of re-coding this from scratch with a custom superview with 8x16 subviews will add so many more problems I will need to solve... Are you sure there's no simple way to get this functionality with a UIButton?  Or else, could you send me a link to a starting point to understand how to do this with a custom superview and subviews?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: @matt More specifically... is there a way to override/inherit the UIButton code, and allow this extra action?  If I slide from the outside of the iPad onto one of the outer buttons, it registers as a "TouchDown" action... is there any conceivable way I can implement this in the middle of a keyboard full of buttons?

Comment: @matt Ok.  That sounds a lot more approachable when you put it that way.  I'm probably gonna put this on the backburner for the moment, because it still seems like it might take a bit more study for me to competently implement, but it definitely sound like the right way to go!  Thanks!  If you wouldn't mind restating your answer briefly below, I will select your answer as correct to this problem.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using the built-in control events of the buttons, for the simple reason that you don't get an event in a button at all unless the touch is initially *in* that button (as I explain here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40414929/341994).

Still, this doesn't sound very hard to do. The simplest approach is probably to put the touch response (such as a gesture recognizer) into the common superview of all the buttons. The superview can then track the gesture. And it can very easily find out which button the touch is currently inside at any given moment. So it can manage the whole interaction. It can even send messages to the buttons telling them when to highlight and unhighlight. (And if you aren't going to use the button touch handling for anything, you might even want to give up the idea that these *are* buttons; they could just be views or custom controls that look like buttons.)